# Where does the MoveIT EZ software store its default log files?

Tags: ftp, log-files, sftp

According to their website (http://www.ipswitchft.com/products/moveit/client/), the software stores two log files:

> MOVEit EZ automatically creates and
>   maintains two log files: a daily,
>   end-user oriented log that records all
>   transfers, successful and not; and a
>   support staff oriented technical
>   “debug” log that records each step of
>   each transfer.

Where are the log files stored by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool appears to log significant data in the Windows System Event Log.

Beyond that, depending on the version of the software that's being used, you may locate log files in any of the following locations:

- The active local system directory
- The user's profile directory (for the user running the software)
- The system user's profile directory
- A custom location, as defined with the "Options"->"Logging" menu item